# Копирование файлов при сборке контейнера Docker

Tags: docker

При выполнении директивы COPY в процессе BUILD, если в контейнере по месту куда копируются файлы уже были какие-то из копируемых, но в копируемых изменены не все файлы, а только некоторые, в новый образ попадут все файлы, которые копируются или только измененные/добавленные файлы? Вопрос связи с тем, не будет ли проблем с “раздутием” образов при каждом обновлении образа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что вас интересует совсем не то, что вы спросили.

Собирайте обновлённые образы **не поверх предыдущих, а на той же основе**.

Кстати, собирая обновлённый образ по тому же самому `Dockerfile`, вы это и сделаете, потому что в нём нет никаких директив брать предыдущую версию образа за основу.

*Во всяком случае, изначально. Первую версию из предыдущей собрать же нельзя, верно?*

---

А по тому, что спросили — не уверен, что это поведение вообще определено и не зависит от драйвера дисковых томов.

Но проблема раздутия определённо будет иметь место, потому что в результате перезаписи файла из предыдущего слоя при сборке образа сохраняется необходимость этот предыдущий слой иметь, даже если его содержимое частично будет стёрто. Поэтому лучший вариант, если предыдущий слой имеет большую часть ненужных или избыточных данных — избавиться от него. См. выше.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Почему вопрос стоял именно так - хочется максимально уменьшить время создания образов с новой версией сервиса (образа контейнера), и в новом слое изменять только то, что было изменено и не проходить с нуля весь процесс воссоздания окружения для сервиса внутри контейнера. С другой стороны, есть требование иметь образы под каждую версию сервиса чтобы можно было откатиться.
В тоже время, команды для воссоздания окружения (вроде, apt-get install) планируется выносить в отдельные скрипты, которые будут вызываться из Dockerfile, и скрипты могут меняться по мере развития сервиса.

Comment: @Bambuk Чтобы хранить все версии, достаточно не удалять старые. Измерьте, насколько в вашем случае быстрее делать образ с предыдущего состояния -- скорее всего, примерно на ноль. Ещё можно подумать о подготовке своего базового образа.